# Paint on mesh for makeover

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, shader, paint, projection

I'm now struggling for weeks on a part of the game I'm making.
As a beginner in Unity and programming, I need your experience and advice to understand how can I paint on skinned mesh like this (from 1:10):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grVEK1Bb6ZM

I spend a lot of time to find a solution with no result. (Decal shader to separate texture, paint on mesh with alpha, project texture, merge texture .. ). But these solutions look bad for mobile or not exactly what I need.

So If someone know a way to do that, even a little info or anything, that will drive my research, it's very welcome.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The example you provide limits the range of the painting with a bitmap mask (ie on the eyebrows, or on the lips), so the painting is only meant for a more enjoyable UX. If this is what you need, you should probably do something like this:

You need to know where the mouse is interacting with the model. Raycasting is expensive and requires to update the colliders every frame, since you character is skinned. If you use the masking trick of your example, this dramatically reduces the amount of computation, since you could pass a subset of the mesh containing only that specific area (maybe just the face for ex)

see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SkinnedMeshRenderer.BakeMesh.html
and https://answers.unity.com/questions/39490/collider-on-skinned-mesh.html

(if you can't, there could be other tricks, like rendering the character's UV into a separate float buffer/texture, and sample that buffer using the mouse position)

Once you can raycast the mesh you can fetch the UV position of the hit
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-textureCoord.html

Using those UVs you can write to a texture, or instance particles/objects on a render target etc (there are many options here).

You then need to combine that texture with the bitmap mask in the shader of the character.